# How to transpose CSV data

Tags: php, email, csv

I am a newbie to PHP and have managed to get this working by using various bits of code I have put together. However I need help with transposing the data.

At the moment I get:

title, forename, surname, dob, high
mr, fred, evans, 01/06/79, yes

But what I require is:

title, mr

forname, fred

surname, evans

dob, 01/06/79

high, yes.

Here is my code:

```
$message = "". 
"title: $title" . "\n" . 
"forename: $forename" . "\n" . 
"surname: $surname"; 
"DOB: $dob";
"high: $high";

//The Attachment 

$cr = "\n"; 
$data = "Title" . ',' . "Forename" . ',' . "Surname" . ',' . "DOB" . ',' . "High Blood Pressure" . $cr; 
$data .= "$title" . ',' . "$forename" . ',' . "$surname" . ',' . "$dob" . ',' . "$high" . $cr; 
$fp = fopen('file.csv','a'); 
fwrite($fp,$data); 
fclose($fp); 

$attachments[] = Array( 
'data' => $data, 
'name' => 'file.csv', 
'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel' 
);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: if there's more than oner pseron that's a bad csv file(format), and its type is not 'application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you write to the CSV is controlled by you.  Currently you're writing out this:

```
$data = "Title" . ',' . "Forename" . ',' . "Surname" . ',' . "DOB" . ',' . "High Blood Pressure" . $cr; 
$data .= "$title" . ',' . "$forename" . ',' . "$surname" . ',' . "$dob" . ',' . "$high" . $cr;
```

Change those lines so that its like this:

```
$data = "Title," . $title . "\n";
$data .= "Forename," . $forename . "\n";
//...
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I did try that but missed the additional full stop at the beginning so it was over writing the data on line one.